# How to download several pdf files as a zip file?

Tags: angular6, jszip

I already have a function that download several files separeted.
I need to download it wrapped into an unique zip file. Can somebody help me with that?
This is what a get so far:

**service.ts**

```
download(mercado: string, data: Date, formato: string): Observable<Blob> {
    const _data = formatDate(data, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'pt');

    return this.http
      .get(`${API_URL}/api/nota-de-corretagem/download/${mercado}/${_data}/${formato}`, {
      responseType: 'blob'
    });
}
```

**component.ts**

```
download(notas: Models.NotaDeCorretagem[]) {
    let notasChecked = notas.filter(f => f.selected === true);
    notas
    .filter(n => n.selected === true)
    .forEach(n => {
      this.notsvc.download(n.mercado, n.data, 'pdf')
        .subscribe(
          (blob) => {
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = n.mercado + '_' + moment(n.data).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '.pdf';
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            a.remove();
            this.erro = false;
          },
            (err) => {
              console.log('download error:', JSON.stringify(err));
              this.erro = true;
            }
          );
        });       
      }
```

Comment: Your backend would need to provide you with an endpoint to do what you're trying to do. It's not something you can do on frontend alone.